# not authorized to perform: SNS:ListTopics on resource: arn:aws:sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

i'm facing the below error while specifying the specific resource but if i use * it is working fine. Please suggest.

Error :

```
com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AuthorizationErrorException: User: arn:aws:sts::11111111:
assumed-role/iam-role_test/1234567 is not authorized to perform: SNS:ListTopics on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:11111111:* 
(Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: fae398a7-b776-5643-9f30-ce5a80344)
```

Below is the policy :

```
  ICMEC2Policy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      PolicyName: pe_test
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'SNS:ListTopics'
              - 'SNS:Publish'
              - 'SNS:Unsubscribe'
              - 'SNS:ListTagsForResource'
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:workflow-alerts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error message, it might be that in the code your user tries to list all topics and not just the one you provided it access to

Comment: Thank you Oleksii Donoha .. Yes, it is required full permissions for Listtopics 

1. * With listTopics permission
2. With topicName and other permission